# Accessing nested JSON objects in Backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js, eco

I've a simple scenario where I return JSON with nested objects with a Rails backend. I'm having trouble accessing the attributes of the nested object.

Example JSON:

```
[{
  category_id: 2,
  id: 34,
  name: "red",
  category: {
    name: "color"
  }
},
{
  category_id: 2,
  id: 35,
  name: "blue",
  category: {
    name: "color"
  }
}]
```

Say I want to access category color for item with an id of 35, this works fine in the console:

```
collection = new App.Collections.Colors()
collection.fetch()
model = collection.get(35)
model.get('category').name
```

Within my eco templates, I get the error, "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined." However, my template still shows I can access the object with [object Object] if I only indicate

```
<%= model.get('category') %>
```

Any ideas? I'm sure I'm not understanding something fundamental.

**UPDATED**

I realized some category names were nil which was causing the error. The above code should be fine.

Comment: I'm just realizing not all my items have a name stored, which was throwing the undefined error. I should be more careful :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your JSON is malformed.

As per JSON spec, you need to wrap the keys with quotation marks.

Try the following instead:

```
[{
  "category_id": 2,
  "id": 34,
  "name": "red",
  "category": {
    "name": "color"
  }
},
{
  "category_id": 2,
  "id": 35,
  "name": "blue",
  "category": {
    "name": "color"
  }
}]
```

Comment: John, good catch, although it ended up that some of my category names were nil, which was throwing the error!

Comment: Ah I see. Then you could have something such as

`<% if (typeof model != 'undefined' && typeof model.get('category') != 'undefined' && typeof model.get('category').name != 'undefined' {  %>
 <%= model.get('category').name %>
<% } %>` to ensure that name is not nil